# Ultrafilter Principle + Hausdorffness as a substitute of the Axiom of Choice

Tags: general-topology, logic, soft-question, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

In his book 'Handbook of Analysis and its Foundations', Schechter suggests how, for Hausdorff spaces, the Axiom of Choice may be substituted by the Ultrafilter Principle.
In particular he notices how one of the most important equivalent formulations of the Axiom of Choice, the **Tychonov Product Theorem** takes the following, obvious, form for the Hausdorff spaces:

An arbitrary product of compact Hausdorff spaces is compact

The surprising fact is, this is  an equivalent statement to the **Ultrafilter Princple**, which is in general strictly weaker than the AOC.
Anyway the author does not develop further.

Now what I would like to know is:

- Can we make the substitution "UF+H=AC" more precise, in general topology?
- We do not have a notion of Hausdorfness in other context than topology, as far as I know. Can we nonetheless impose some other hypotheses on our (structured) set to substitute the AC with UF? If yes, do these hypotheses share someting with Hausdorfness?

Comment: What does UF+H=AC even mean?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I mean if in Hausdorff spaces we can always substitute the Ultrafilter Principeple with the Axiom of Choice. "." Are precisely intended to convey the idea that I do not know if this statement is precise or not

Comment: That's not particularly true in general. Just for products of compact spaces.

Comment: As a good starting point it might help to consider a less ambitious question: "Are there other examples of theorems in topology which require full AC in general but UF alone (or some other weak fragment of AC) suffices in the context of Hausdorff spaces?" My worry is that this particular situation, without more supporting evidence, seems like it might just be a coincidence.

Comment: @NoahSchweber yes, I precisely meani this kind of question. As you remark, we would need some other evidence. What struck me was the fact that the author presented it as a quite general fact

Comment: The key point of Hausdorff spaces is that limits are unique. When something is unique, that means we do not need AC to choose it. The question, ultimately, is what kind of things require you to choose limits from Hausdorff spaces... ultimately this is mostly about compactness.

Comment: @AsafKaragila you are right. The thing is, with unique limits a proof technique the author calls "Kelley's Choice" is simplified, and does not need the Axiom of Choice. But this is mainly about compactness _and_ products: a rather narrow environment

Comment: @AsafKaragila, anyway, I notice you from the blog you are a great expert in Choice! I would be curious about other contexts where some paricular unrelated property of the object we are studying (e.g. Hausdorfness for topological spaces) can lower the 'choice power' we need, particularly, but not only, in general topology.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If you want to only work in "nice" spaces (i.e. Separable, Hausdorff, Locally Compact,..) You can usually just get away with a countable axiom of choice (as opposed to full choice), and it's arguably more constructive than an Ultrafilter approach.

Comment: @Drewrl3v: I don't see how that's related here.

Comment: @Francesco: Again, you essentially need to eliminate choices, or at least reduce them somehow (e.g. prove that there are only finitely many of them, etc.) To answer your question is to write a book about weak axioms of choice. You can start with Herrlich's "The Axiom of Choice", which is an example of a book *somehow* similar to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is general topology / functional analysis on Hausdorff spaces (and not want to prove all ideals are contained in a maximal ideal, or want to use Zorn's lemma in another setting) you probably could get away with the UFP alone. But choosing foundations is done for all mathematicians, not just those in some subfield. It's sort of "Reverse foundations": how many and what axioms do I need to prove my result? I don't think Schechter proposes to replace AC by UFP in general, he just wants to make a point that in analysis one rarely needs full choice, and that many forms of choice one does need are equivalent to UFP. OTOH he probably does want cardinal numbers to be in a total ordering (and IIRC that's equivalent to AC?) and analysis is not an island onto itself. I wouldn't take his remarks on this too seriously.